# Getting jetty to log with the correct timezone

Tags: logging, jetty

I'm using Jetty 8 and am configuring my jetty.xml to customise the requests.log files.

My problem is, Jetty is serving the logs with a timestamp in the GMT timezone - I'm in the UK but its now summer time (GMT+1, aka, BST). Probably because of:

```
<Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>
```

How do I get Jetty to serve the logs using whatever the local time on the server is (which is correct)?
Simply removing the `<Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT</Set>` didn't do anything, and I don't want to have to manually change it every 6ish months.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Jetty NCSARequestLog uses [java.util.TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html).

`GMT` is the default for NCSA formatted log files, as this is what various log analysis tools expects.

It sounds like you want the NCSA formatted logs to use a timezone that is daylight savings aware.  In that case you have really 1 choice, use the long format Timezone appropriate for your system and environment.

Here's the details about London, England: http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/city.html?n=136

What you need is a TimeZone string that will identified by your system. Which means:

- TimeZone identifier does not use GMT offset notation
- TimeZone identifier is not 3-letters (see [javadoc section about "Three-letter time zone IDs"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html))
- TimeZone identifier is long form.

Create a simple Java source file and run (on your system) the following code.

```java
package time;

import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TZDump
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        TimeZone mytz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        System.out.printf("The TimeZone for this machine: %s%n", mytz);
        for (String string : TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(mytz.getRawOffset())) {
            System.out.println(string);
        }   
    }
}
```

So for my machine, this reports ...

```
SystemV/MST7MDT
US/Arizona
US/Mountain
```

I'm lucky, as this is list is small, and a bonus for me is that where I live Daylights Savings Time is not observed.   In my case, I'll use `"US/Arizona"`.

In your case, you'll see a larger list (just because you are so close to Europe).
Choose an entry that starts with `"Europe/"` (I'm guessing yours will be `"Europe/London"`)

Now use that long form TimeZone identifier in your configuration.

```xml
<Set name="LogTimeZone">Europe/London</Set>
```