# How to change timezone for Jetty request log *filenames*?

Tags: java, logging, jetty

I have configured request logs as seen below - in **jetty.xml**. However, the **LogTimeZone** which is set to **GMT-5** below will only change the timezone of the log entries in request.yyyy_mm_dd.log but the filename of request.**yyyy_mm_dd.log** doesn't reflect "**GMT-5**". As an example, with the below setting when I started Jetty (01/28/2014), it generated log files with file names - **request.2014_56_28.log**. Not sure where "**56**" came from for the file name "**request.2014_56_28.log**" Any suggestion would be of big help!!

```
 <Ref id="Handlers">
  <Call name="addHandler">
    <Arg>
      <New id="RequestLog" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler">
        <Set name="requestLog">
          <New id="RequestLogImpl" class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.NCSARequestLog">
            <Set name="filename">
               logs/request.yyyy_mm_dd.log
            </Set>
            <Set name="filenameDateFormat">yyyy_mm_dd</Set>
            <Set name="retainDays">365</Set>
            <Set name="append">true</Set>
            <Set name="extended">false</Set>
            <Set name="logCookies">false</Set>
            <Set name="LogTimeZone">GMT-5</Set>
          </New>
        </Set>
      </New>
    </Arg>
  </Call>
</Ref>
```

Answer (score 1):

> What you need is a TimeZone string that will identified by your system. Which means:

```
TimeZone identifier does not use GMT offset notation
TimeZone identifier is not 3-letters (see javadoc section about "Three-letter time zone IDs")
TimeZone identifier is long form.
```

**References**

- [Getting jetty to log with the correct timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058343/getting-jetty-to-log-with-the-correct-timezone)
- [java.util.TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)

Comment: thanks, Paul! I will check them out and will get back to you.